# Modifying values of small slice of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to center (subtract the average) of slice of a column. So in the following example I would search by supercase (the var that groups observations take their average, then assign, in the same position, the old value minus the average). I was working with a bigger dataframe (477 rows × 85 columns) so I did a test df to show my point

```
import random as rd

# 10 row by 3 columns dataframe with random floats
test = pd.DataFrame([[rd.random() for n in range(3)] for n in range(10)], columns = ["Var{}".format(n+1) for n in range(3)])
# supercase column to group observations (rows)
test["supercase"]=[1000]*2+[2000]*4+[3000]*3+[4000]
# random metadata for fluff
for n,_lett in zip(range(3),list("abc")):
    test["metadata{}".format(n+1)]=[_lett*int(rd.random()*10) for i in range(len(test.index))]

# get the vars I want to work on
_vars = test.columns[:3]
# get a list of supercases to work on
supercases = test.supercase.unique()

# go through the calculations
for var in _vars:
    for sc in supercases:
        test[var][test.supercase == sc]=test[var][test.supercase == sc]-test[var][test.supercase == sc].mean()
```

(I realize that a group with one observation will have a centered value of zero)

Nevertheless, and after waiting for quite a bit (with the original df), I get the following warning:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\__main__.py:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I wasn't sure what that really meant, so I tried creating a copy of the df and do the attributions on the new df:
test_ctr = pd.DataFrame(test) #to avoid two vars pointing to a same object.

```
for var in _vars:
    for sc in supercases:
        test_ctr[var][test_ctr.supercase == sc]=test[var][test.supercase == sc]-test[var][test.supercase == sc].mean()
```

This made me notice that both test_ctr (as expected) and test were being modified which made me more confused.

How should this be done then?
The link above describes the following as the proper way which would make have to save index values:

```
dfc.loc[0,'A'] = 11
```

Is there something that I'm missing? Specially in the case of the test df being modified?

Cheers and Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I can give you a great explanation for that warning beyond what's in the documentation, but it appears what you did works fine and that warning doesn't always apply even when it appears.

Nevertheless, there's a much faster and easier way to do what you want that is fairly close to a `groupby()` example in the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation).

```
test[['Var1','Var2','Var3','supercase']]

       Var1      Var2      Var3  supercase
0  0.107989  0.275314  0.688784       1000
1  0.743372  0.726421  0.457137       1000
2  0.946661  0.469229  0.145584       2000
3  0.562564  0.040528  0.150148       2000
4  0.213042  0.934673  0.713870       2000
5  0.851200  0.371629  0.239308       2000
6  0.555617  0.502027  0.862414       3000
7  0.386040  0.954245  0.392592       3000
8  0.431534  0.088997  0.016639       3000
9  0.207693  0.269625  0.189688       4000

test.groupby('supercase')[_vars].transform( lambda x: x - x.mean() )

       Var1      Var2      Var3
0 -0.317692 -0.225554  0.115823
1  0.317692  0.225554 -0.115823
2  0.303294  0.015214 -0.166643
3 -0.080803 -0.413487 -0.162079
4 -0.430325  0.480658  0.401643
5  0.207833 -0.082386 -0.072920
6  0.097887 -0.013063  0.438533
7 -0.071691  0.439156 -0.031290
8 -0.026196 -0.426092 -0.407242
9  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

In terms of getting a copy of a dataframe, this is the standard way:

```
test_ctr = test.copy()
```

I would have guessed that what you tried `test_ctr = pd.DataFrame(test)` would have also worked but apparently not!

Comment: Many thanks for the groupby(), indeed I'm not used to it. I would expect that the test_ctr = pd.DataFrame(test) would work as it's the way you do it with basic objects e.g. x = list(y)!